# Oracle get rank for only latest date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have origin table A:

| dt | c1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/10/1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022/10/2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022/10/3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022/10/1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022/10/2 | 2 | 6 |
| 2022/10/3 | 2 | 5 |

Currently I got the latest dt's `percent_rank` by:

```sql
select * from
(
select
*,
percent_rank() over (partition by c1 order by value) as prank
from A
) as pt
where pt.dt = Date'2022-10-3'
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXynTaD5nmLqFJdjDSCZpL/0

the excepted result looks like:

| dt | c1 | value | prank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/10/3 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022/10/3 | 2 | 5 | 0.5 |

Which means at 2022-10-3, the value in c1 group's percent_rank in history is 100% while in c2 group is 66%.

But this sql will sort evey partition which I thought it's time complexity is `O(n log n)`.

I just need the latest date's rank and I thought I could do that by calculating `count(last_value > value)/count()` which cost `O(n)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do there? Could you please show the expected result and explain the intended logic? Why to use percent_rank here?

Comment: Sadly couldn't post answer but why don't you use ORDER BY dt DESC>

Comment: you should also post the desired result, because we don't understand what you want to obtain. And also it is best to create also a fiddle with the data on fiddle.com.

Comment: @FlorinGhita, I have create a fiddle db link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXynTaD5nmLqFJdjDSCZpL/0

Comment: Your title says Oracle, but you tagged MySQL and your code is syntactically invalid for Oracle. Which RDBMS are you using as MySQl and Oracle are two different RDBMSes.

Comment: So... you want Oracle or Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding the maximum date, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY value) AS prank,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt, c1, value) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-10-01', 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-02', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-03', 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-01', 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-02', 2, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-03', 2, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DT | C1 | VALUE | PRANK | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 5 | .5 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CEvy0-zS)

> But this sql will sort every partition which I thought it's time complexity is O(n log n).

Whatever you do you will need to iterate over the entire result-set.

> I just need the latest date's rank and I thought I could do that by calculating `count(last_value > value)/count()`.

Then you will need to find the last value which (unless you are hardcoding the last date) will involve using an index- or table-scan over all the values in each partition and sorting the values and then to find a count of the greater values will require a second index- or table-scan. You can profile both solutions but I expect you would find that using analytic functions is going to be equally efficient, if not better, than trying to use aggregation functions.

For example:

```sql
SELECT c1,
       dt,
       value,
       ( SELECT ( COUNT(CASE WHEN value <= t.value THEN 1 END) - 1 )
                / ( COUNT(*) - 1 )
         FROM   table_name c
         WHERE  c.c1 = t.c1
       ) AS prank
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  dt = DATE '2022-10-03'
```

If going to access the table twice and you are likely to find that the I/O costs of table access are going to far outweight any potential savings from using a different method. However, if you look at the explain plan ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QNWTyplH)) then the query is still performing an aggregate sort so there is not going to be any cost savings, only additional costs from this method.

Comment: My problem is not to find the latest date, assume I already have it just like in my SQL. The point is calculate `percent_rank` is a sorting problem, which consume much more time than just iterate table once.

Comment: @PaleNeutron As I stated at the end of the answer, to calculate the equivalent of `percent_rank` using alternate methods you will have to manually implement the functionality of `percent_rank` and are going to (effectively) perform the same sorting and it is almost certainly going to be more efficient to use a solution implemented by the database designers than to try to hand-craft a solution. What you are asking appears to be premature optimisation but if you really want to test it then implement an alternate solution using aggregation and profile both solutions.

Comment: So in short, `sorting` is not as expensive as I thought in database? But I do not know how to implement my `O(n)` way in sql.

Comment: @PaleNeutron See the update in the answer. I think you are overestimating the cost that you can achieve in your theoretical analysis. Instead you should look at the explain plans and see what the database is actually going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t.c1, t.dt, t.value
from TABLENAME t
inner join (
    select c1, max(dt) as MaxDate
    from TABLENAME
    group BY dt
) tm on t.c1 = tm.c1 and t.dt = tm.MaxDate ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

Or as simple as

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I need percent rank of the latest date (which could be get by another query).

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled it a bit, it is almost the same answer as MT0 already put.

```
select dt, c1, val, prank*100 as percent_rank  from   (select 
     t1.*, 
     percent_rank() over (partition by c1 order by val) as prank,
     row_number() over (partition by c1 order by dt desc) rn    from t1) where rn=1;
```

result

```
DT          C1  VAL PERCENT_RANK
2022-10-03  1   3   100
2022-10-03  2   5   50
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec60a/23

I used Row_number = 1 to get the latest date.
And also pushed the percent_rank as percent.
Is this what you desire?